# Best inheritance / interface structure for storing many game constants?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, static

I have game data structured like this:

```
public class CraftableFireTower
{
    public static List<ResourceNumber> RequiredResources = new List<ResourceNumber>
    {
        new ResourceNumber(ResourceType.WOOD, 100),
        new ResourceNumber(ResourceType.STONE, 50)
    };
}

public class CraftableFrostTower
{
    public static List<ResourceNumber> RequiredResources = new List<ResourceNumber>
    {
        new ResourceNumber(ResourceType.WOOD, 120),
        new ResourceNumber(ResourceType.STONE, 70)
    };
}
```

Which combination of interfaces, abstract classes, inheritance, static methods / classes can I use to make them generic so I can pass them into methods like this without creating new instances of classes every time?

```
    if (inventory.HasResourcesFor(CraftableFireTower))
    {
        inventory.RemoveResourcesFor(CraftableFireTower);
        serverWorld.BuildFireTower(position));
    }
```

I tried an interface, but I can't have static methods on an interface. I tried an abstract class but I can't make a static abstract class or a static abstract method. Is what I'm trying to do impossible? Is there a better way to structure hard-coded grouped numbers/constants for game data?

Comment: Would it be an option to use attributes on the class instead of a static member?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of multiple ways, here's a simple one:

Create a class Attribute named `RequiredResourcesAttribute`, then you could add you your class like this:

```
public class RequiredResourceAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; } 

    public RequiredResourceAttribute( int qty ){ 
       Quantity = qty;
    }
}
```

Create wood:

```
public class RequiredWoodAttribute : RequiredSourceAttribute
{
    public RequiredWoodAttribute ( int qty ) : base(qty ){ 
    }

}
```

Then use them....

```
[RequiredWood(100)]
[RequiredStone(50)]
public class CraftableFireTower
{

}
```

Then you could modify your `HasResourcesFor()` by looking at the Resource attributes of the class.  You could easily keep a cached list of types and their resources so you wouldn't have to reflect the class attributes more than 1 making this very fast and easy to maintain.

I like the idea of having classes for each craftable object, if in the future (or now) you need varying ways of how these objects handle events or other game related logic then the class will allow you handle that uniquely.

So keep a single instance of `Dictionary<Type,List<RequiredResourceAttribute>>` in some class as a static member.

```
private Dictionary<Type,List<RequiredResourceAttribute>> _requiredResources = new Dictionary<Type,List<RequiredResourceAttribute>>();

//validate a type has the required resources..
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeping a cached list of types and their resources? How ugly would the reflection be in order to fetch attributes off classes and how fast is it?

Comment: ugh, i gotta run.. be back in a hour.. look up how to find attribs on a Type

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not making them static.

I would not try to combine the definition of a `CraftableFireTower` with an *instance* of a `CraftableFireTower`. In your game, you have a catalog of units, `CraftableFireTower` being one of them. This catalog need only contain an entry for each type of unit. In this sense, the resource cost list will only be created once per catalog.

If the player creates an instance of a `CraftableFireTower`, that should be a separate object which refers to the catalog item to define the unit price.

... In other words, you should have two objects: `CraftableFireTowerDefinition` with things like the base attributes that all craftable fire towers have, including resource cost, damage attributes, HP, whatever.

Then you have `CraftableFireTowerInstance`, or even more generally `ItemInstance`, which has a reference to the `CraftableFireTowerDefinition`.

illustration:

```
interface UnitDefinition
{
    public ResourceCost resourceCost;
    public string name;
}

class FireTowerDefinition : UnitDefinition
{
    public ResourceCost resourceCost = new ResourceCost(50, 50, 20);
    public string name = "Fire Tower";
}

class UnitInstance
{
    public UnitDefinition unitDefinition;

    public int HP;
    public Point PositionOnMap;
    // etc... and other attributes that are per instance
}


....

class MyGame
{
    // this list is pretty much static...
    public UnitDefinition[] catalog = { new FireTowerDefinition(), new OtherThingDefinition() };

    // this list changes throughout gameplay
    public List<UnitInstances> unitInstances;
}
```

You may not even need the `FireTowerDefinition` class... the base class `UnitDefinition` might be enough for everything in the catalog.

Comment: How would I look things up in the catalog? Iterating through the whole list every time seems inefficient. If I change the array to a dictionary, presumably i'd need an enum to index by, which i'm trying to get away from, so I can define a new tower in just 1 place.

Comment: Normally you would not need to look anything up, because your unit instances just refer directly to the catalog entry. For example if you want to know the total starting HP of a tower that the user selects, `selectedItemInstance.unitDefinition.StartingHP` or whatever. No need to consult the catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I think a factory class which could be queried to find the cost of something but also returns instances of those things if requested.

```
MetaInfo fireMeta = new MetaInfo(100, 50);

Factory.RegisterCraftable(CraftableFireTower, fireMeta);
```

with

```
Factory.GetRequirements<CraftableFireTower>();
```

and

```
Factory.New<CraftableFireTower>();
```

Internally the factory just uses a dictionary to store meta information about each craftable instance such as resources and build time.

The idea as others have mentioned is to separate information about the class from the class itself

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't think you need an interface or an abstract class, or one class per item.  I think you one class, call it `CraftableItem`:

```
public class CraftableItem 
{
    public List<ResourceNumber> RequiredResources = new List<ResourceNumber>();

    // Other properties / methods
}

Then you have one global property in your program for each resource:

CraftableItem CraftableFireTower {
    get { 
        if ( _CraftableFireTower == null ) {
            _CraftableFireTower = new CraftableItem();
            _CraftableFireTower.Add( new ResourceNumber( ResourceType.WOOD, 100 );
            _CraftableFireTower.Add( new ResourceNumber( ResourceType.STONE, 50);
        }
        return _CraftableFireTower; 
    }
}
private CraftableItem _CraftableFireTower
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you aim to do:

```
if (inventory.HasResourcesFor(CraftableFireTower)) {
  inventory.RemoveResourcesFor(CraftableFireTower);
  serverWorld.BuildFireTower(position));
}
```

This is perfectly reasonable, and classes, interfaces and the like are not the solution. I would always recommend data over code, and data structuring over inheritance.

Make CraftableFireTower an enum value, store the data (Resources) in a Dictionary, write your code to act on attributes of the data objects, not on the names themselves. It's simple and extensible. I think most games evolve in that direction eventually, if not at the outset. It's sometimes referred to as an Entity-Component System or ECS.

More info in this question: [In C++, should different game entities have different classes? Or should it be in one class which contains all behaviours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901507/in-c-should-different-game-entities-have-different-classes-or-should-it-be-i/21730357#21730357).